# AWS amplify sets up an error message for the required field instead of the standard "Please fill in this field" browser popup

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, aws-amplify

Is there a way to customize AWS amplify required field is missing instead of standard "Please fill in this field" browser popup ?

Below is code demonstrating the current logic that has been implemented:

```
      <amplify-authenticator [hideSignUp]="true" [services]="services" [formFields]='formFields' >
        <ng-template amplifySlot="header">
          <div class='header'>
            <h3 class='header-text'>{{'Sign in'  | amplifyHeader : authenticator?.route | translate }}</h3>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template amplifySlot="sign-in-header"></ng-template>
        <ng-template amplifySlot="reset-password-header" ngIf='false'></ng-template>
        <ng-template amplifySlot="confirm-reset-password-header" ngIf='false'></ng-template>
        <ng-template amplifySlot="confirm-sign-in-header"></ng-template>
        <ng-template amplifySlot="force-new-password-header"></ng-template>
        <ng-template amplifySlot="confirm-reset-password-footer" >
            <button amplify-button type="button" class="amplify-button amplify-button--link amplify-button--small amplify-button--fullwidth" (click)='authenticator.toSignIn()'>{{ 'Back to Sign in' | translate }}</button>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template
          amplifySlot="authenticated"
          let-user="user"
          let-signOut="signOut"
        >
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template amplifySlot="confirm-sign-in-footer">
            <div class='amplify-custom-footer'>
                <button class='amplify-custom-button fill' (click)='resendCode()'>{{'Resend Code' | translate | uppercase}}</button>
                <button class='amplify-custom-button outline' type="submit">{{ 'Confirm' | translate | uppercase }}</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class='amplify-button amplify-button--link amplify-button--small amplify-button--fullwidth' (click)='authenticator.toSignIn()'>Back To Sign In</button>
            </div>
        </ng-template>


        <ng-template amplifySlot="confirm-reset-password-footer">
            <div class='amplify-custom-footer'>
                <div class='amplify-custom-button fill' (click)='resendCodeForgotPassword()' >{{'Resend Code' | translate | uppercase}}</div>
                <button class='amplify-custom-button outline' type="submit">{{ 'Confirm' | translate | uppercase}}</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class='amplify-button amplify-button--link amplify-button--small amplify-button--fullwidth' (click)='authenticator.toSignIn()'>{{ 'Back To Sign in' | translate }}</button>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
      </amplify-authenticator>
```

[image]